# Why isn't Angular expiring cached JSON?

Tags: android, json, angularjs, cordova, browser-cache

I have an Phonegap/Ionic/Angular app which does not seem to want to expire any JSON files that I cache.

Here's an example of the $http call that I make.

```
$http.get(apiUrl, { cache: true })
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        if (data) {
            // successfully retrieved facilities
            facilities = data;
            deferred.resolve(facilities);
        } else {
            deferred.reject('nodata');
        }
    })
```

I've only observed this behavior on Android devices. The iOS devices seem to be updating the data fine.

On Android, one QA user was able to uninstall the app and re-install it immediately and still see the old data. Closing the app and swiping it away doesn't expire the cache. The only thing that worked was force stopping the app and deleting the data for the app in the App Info area.